# Definition of correlated Brownian motion with given covariance matrix

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If $(B_1,B_2)$ is said to be a correlated 2 dimensional Brownian motion with correlation matrix $S\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ with $S_{11}=S_{22}=1$, $S_{12}=S_{21}=\rho$, does this mean $dB_1dB_2=\rho\,dt$?

I would appreciate a definition of correlated Brownian motion specified by a correlation matrix, and a reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If $W=(W^{1}, W^{2}, \ldots, W^{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a vector of independent standard Brownian motion defined on a certain probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, (\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \ge 0}\mathbb{P})$ and $A \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$  is a matrix with real entries, then the vector $B=(B^{1}, B^{2}, \ldots, B^{m})$ defined by:
$$B=AW$$
satisfies:
$$\mathbb{E}(B^{i}_{t}B^{j}_{t})=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k}a_{ik}W^{k}_{t}\sum_{l}a_{jl}W^{l}_{t}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left( \sum_{k}a_{ik}a_{jk}(W^{k}_{t})^{2}\right)=t\sum_{k}a_{ik}a_{jk}$$
and now it is apparent that the covariance matrix of the random vector $B$ (which is usually called correlated Brownian motion) is given by $AA^{t}$.